# What's the purpose of deferred callbacks in libevent?

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming, libevent

According to [the libevent book](http://www.wangafu.net/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html):

> **Deferred callbacks**
>
> By default, a bufferevent callbacks are executed immediately when the
> corresponding condition happens. (This is true of evbuffer callbacks
> too; we’ll get to those later.) This immediate invocation can make
> trouble when dependencies get complex. For example, suppose that there
> is a callback that moves data into evbuffer A when it grows empty, and
> another callback that processes data out of evbuffer A when it grows
> full. ***Since these calls are all happening on the stack, you might risk
> a stack overflow if the dependency grows nasty enough.***
>
> To solve this, you can tell a bufferevent (or an evbuffer) that its
> callbacks should be deferred. When the conditions are met for a
> deferred callback, rather than invoking it immediately, it is queued
> as part of the event_loop() call, and invoked after the regular
> events' callbacks.

As described above:

1. The event loop fetches a batch of events, and processes them one by one immediately.
2. Before the fetched events are processed, any new event won't be fetched and processed.
3. If an event was marked as `BEV_OPT_DEFER_CALLBACKS`, then it will be processed after all other events in the same batch are processed.

Provided two callbacks `ca` and `cb`. First, `ca` is called, `ca` finds `evbuffer_A` is empty, then writes a message into it.

Then, `cb` is called, and `cb` finds `evbuffer_A` contains a message, then fetch and send it out.

When `cb` is called, `ca`'s stack has been released. I think there won't be a stack overflow in such a scenario.

So, my question is:

**What's the purpose of deferred callbacks in libevent?**

Comment: The purpose is explained in the text posted... can you be more specific about your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example given in the quoted text is a buffer being filled after one event and emptied after another event.

Consider this **non-event** driven pseudo-code for the same example.

```
void FillBuffer(...)
{
    while (BufferNotFull)
    {
        PutDataInBuffer(...);
    }
    If (BufferIsFull)  // emulates buffer-full event
    {
        ReadBuffer(...);
    }

    ... more code ...
}

void ReadBuffer(...)
{
    while (BufferNotEmpty)
    {
        ReadDataFromBuffer(...);
    }
    If (BufferIsEmpty)  // emulates buffer-empty event
    {
        FillBuffer(...);
    }

    ... more code ...
}
```

Obviously, the condition of the two `if` statements are always true. Consequently the functions never complete but keep calling each other again and again. Sooner or later the stack will overflow.

Now imagine an event driven system where all **callbacks happen as soon as the event triggers** (i.e. remove the `if`-statements but remember that the event-system does the same as the `if`-statements). Like:

```
void FillBuffer(...)  // Called on buffer-empty event
{
    while (BufferNotFull)
    {
        PutDataInBuffer(...);
    }
    // Event buffer-full triggered (i.e. ReadBuffer being called)

    ... more code ...
}

void ReadBuffer(...)  // Called on buffer-full event
{
    while (BufferNotEmpty)
    {
        ReadDataFromBuffer(...);
    }
    // Event buffer-empty triggered (i.e. FillBuffer being called)

    ... more code ...
}
```

Such a system will do the same as the non-event driven pseudo-code, i.e. call the next callback before the first finishes.

Deferred callbacks can solve the problem by letting one callback complete before calling the next callback.

Comment: I am still confused: As calling `FillBuffer` or `ReadBuffer` is an infinite loop, even if they two or one of them are put into the deferred queue, the problem is still there.

Comment: I mean, suppose `FillBuffer` is a callback, even if it is put into the deferred queue, once `FillBuffer` is called, it will never complete. I cannot understand how deferred callbacks solve this problem.

Comment: @xmllmx By using a **deferred callback** for `ReadBuffer` then `FillBuffer` **will finish** before `ReadBuffer` is called (and vice versa). By using a **"immediately" callback**  for `ReadBuffer` then `FillBuffer` **will NOT finish** before `ReadBuffer` is called (and vice versa). That's the difference.

Comment: Consider `FillBuffer` and `ReadBuffer` are two regular functions, will calling `FillBuffer` finish?

Comment: @xmllmx Not in my psedo-code but in the real code (i.e. **without** the `if` statement) then **yes, it will finish**. And in something like `main` you can do alternating calls of `FillBuffer` and `ReadBuffer`. That's (more or less) what an even-driven system **with deferred callback** will do.

Comment: If `FillBuffer` and `ReadBuffer` are not put into deferred queue, I think the `event_loop` will still do alternating calls of `FillBuffer` and `ReadBuffer`. I cannot imagine how they differ from deferred callbacks. Do you mean in a multi-threading environment by default? If in a single thread, even `FillBuffer` triggers another event, the event's callback will not be called until `FillBuffer` is finished.

Comment: @xmllmx Well, I can't explain it better than this. The difference is when the triggered callback is being executed. a) **immediately** (like from an interrupt) or b) **deferred** (like later). You can also use the terms: synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: @xmllmx Your quotes also put it like: `When the conditions are met for a deferred callback, rather than invoking it immediately, it is queued as part of the event_loop() call, and invoked after the regular events' callbacks.`